# Moved Exchange 2010 to a VM, can't decomission original (physical server)

Tags: exchange-2010, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, outlook-2010

We created an exchange VM to replace a physical server, moved the mailboxes after pointing internal and external DNS to it.

Everything works fine, except when I turn off the original machine, about half my users lose connection.

A right click on outlook systray for connection status shows Server 'EXCHANGE01 still in the list **for those failing**...  The same list on failing machines also shows Server exch (the new VM).

**Working users only show connection to Server EXCH in the list.**

All desktops are identical Dell optiplex's running win7 (same image).

I can't quite figure out what's still pointing them to exchange. Their DNS is right, a ping to 'mail' shows the right IP for the exch server...  so it must be something in outlook, or some odd config in the server. The fact that it's roughly half the users is what's throwing me off. All mailboxes are on the new VM.

I have had SOME users succeed by closing outlook and opening it while ONLY the exch server was on, but others doggedly stick to waiting for exchange01.

Stumped

Comment: Did the IP change as well? Sounds like it might be using NetBIOS/WINS to resolve to the old box?

Comment: Since it's only affecting some users I would think it's not a problem with the Service Connection Point in AD but it's worth a look at that to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Did you properly decommission the old Exchange server?  Move all the public folders over?  Using Autodiscover properly?  Check the https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/ site on both valid and invalid clients and note any errors/warnings.

Exchange SCP records in AD and other lingering meta objects will cause issues if you don't decommission it correctly.  You'll also be fighting odd issues and random "ghosts" in the future if you don't properly remove Exchange from a server in the "Exchange Org".  You can't simply shut it down.

Here's an example link/walkthrough: http://www.hemangshah.com/?p=140

However, if you've never done this before, I'd start by doing some research online about how to decommission it.  It isn't hard per say, you just need to be aware that you might run into "gotchas" during the process.

Basically the steps will be (after a known good backup):

1. Move all the mailboxes off the server
2. Move all Public Folders and remove the replicas
3. Remove any arbitration mailboxes (see the link for info) that linger on the old server
4. Verify and then **RE-VERIFY** that all the mailboxes have been moved and clients can connect to their mailboxes on the new server (use OWA or a new Outlook profile as needed)
5. Uninstall Exchange
6. Shutdown old server, clean up any DNS entries if need be, etc.